# How to divide an heap into two sub-heap with heapify for heapsort?

Tags: python, recursion, divide, heapsort

i'm triyng to create an HeapSort function in python, using some auxiliar functions.

I'm trying to follow my book instructions, and using some functions like `fixHeap` which restore the right order in an heap with a node not following rules:

```
def getMaxKnot(i,j,A):
    k = max(A[i],A[j])
    if k==A[i]:
        return i
    if k==A[j]:
        return j


def fixheap(v,H): #basically restore an heap with a node not following heap rules
    if (2*v+1)>len(H)-1:
        return H
    else:
        u=getMaxKnot(2*v+1,2*v+2,H)
        if H[u]>H[v]:
            listoperations.swap(u,v,H) #swap item in position u and v
        return fixheap(u,H)
```

Now, i want basically to create a heapify function which works recursively on left-tree and right-tree, using my function `fixheap` to restore the right order.

My idea was the following:

```
def heapify(A):
        if A==[]:
            return A
        else:
            heapify(LEFT TREE)
            heapify(RIGHT TREE)
            fixheap(0,A)
```

Any ideas on how to divide my Array A into LEFT TREE and RIGHT TREE?

Comment: What is an 'ausiliar function'?

Comment: All the heapify version that i see on the web was based on a single function, wich convert an array to an heap.

So i called fixHeap ausiliar function, but is basically a simple def function

Comment: Auxiliar, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is something missing in `fixheap`. Imagine that the node *v* only has one (left) child, then `getMaxKnot` will trigger an invalid index error, because `j` would point beyond the end of the `A` array.

Personally, I don't think `getMaxKnot` deserves to be a separate function. I would also put the arguments of `fixheap` in the opposite order, so that the second one can be easily omitted and given a default value (when it is the root element). Also swapping two values is really a one-liner:

```
def fixheap(H, v = 0): # put arguments in this order
    u = 2*v + 1
    if u >= len(H):
        return H
    if u+1 < len(H) and H[u+1] > H[u]: # Only compare when there are two child nodes
        u += 1
    if H[u] > H[v]:
        [H[u], H[v]] = [H[v], H[u]] # Swapping is easy
        return fixheap(H, u)
```

Then to your main question: your `heapify` should also get a node as argument, which would be the root of the subtree you want to heapify. The principle is in fact not much different from how the `fixheap` function is used:

```
def heapify(H, v = 0):
    u = 2*v + 1
    if u >= len(H):
        return H
    heapify(H, u)
    if u + 1 < len(H): # make sure there is a right child
        heapify(H, u+1)
    fixheap(H, v)
```

Comment: Finally i solved it on myself. Basically one error is that i was thinking on how to divide left tree and right tree, like splitting my heap into 2- sub list. Instead was just necessary to call heapify to right son and left son using recursion.

My second error was that in heapify, after follow your hint to improve it, i forgot to insert the condition "make a swap only if Parent bigger than Son".

Thanks!